# Android Serialization trouble

Tags: android, serialization

I'm trying to save a list of Locations, but Locations can't be serialized. To manage that, I've made a class called simpleLocation that implements Serialize, and only has the doubles for latitude and longitude:

```
public class simpleLocation implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10001L;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lon = 0.0;

    public simpleLocation()
    {}
    public void setLat(double l)
    {
        lat = l;
    }
    public void setLon(double l)
    {
        lon = l;
    }
    private double getLat()
    {
        return lat;
    }
    public double getLon()
    {
        return lon;
    }

}
```

To the best of my knowledge, I don't need anything else and this class should be serializable. (Then again, my knowledge of serialization is very limited).

I convert my ArrayList of Locations to an ArrayList of simpleLocations, then try to write it out:

```
// dropDownList is a Spinner

private void internalSave()
{
    try{
        // get my internal directory
        String filename = "" + dropDownList.getSelectedItemPosition() + ".ser";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        // convert Locations to simpleLocations
        ArrayList<simpleLocation> simple = convertToSimpleLocation();
        // write out
        for(int i=0; i<simple.size(); i++)
        {
            objectOut.writeObject(simple.get(i));
        }

        objectOut.flush();
        objectOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error with Internal Save:\n"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get a java.io.NotSerializeableException every time I try an use this method, and I can't figure out what's going wrong. I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked, but if someone could point it out I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: Figured it out, I DID need to have a writeObject method in my simpleLocation class.

Comment: can you paste the exception stack trace

Comment: Never mind, I got it! I DO need a writeObject method in my simpleLocation class. Thanks for everyone that was willing to help!

Comment: it should have gone through w/o writeObject method also.